# How do I make the homepage as the blog page?

Tags: homepage, blog, blog-page

In my WordPress website it only has the blog page. There is no home page and other pages. I want the homepage to be the blog page. When I customize the home & blog page to the same page, it prompts the following error.

[image]

I want the blog page URL is configured to the root path. URL has to be www.abc.com (it shows all the blogs) not www.abc.com/blog

Comment: Isn't it the same then as using "Your homepage displays your latest posts"?

Comment: Yeah, I think I figured it out. Rather than setting it to a Static Page, keeping the latest post made my task easier

Answer (score 2):

Choose 'your latest posts' as to what your homepage should show.

This will then show your latest posts on the homepage (aka your blog).

Edit: looks like you have this working now!